# how to shift the figures to below for many figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

This is documentclass:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}%double quotation marks
\usepackage{xcolor}    %%%%% 나중에 지우기 %%%%%
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, caption} 
\usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

This is my full code:

```
 \begin{figure*}[t]
    \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{figs/1.pdf} 
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{figs/2.pdf} 
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:b}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{figs/3.pdf} 
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:c}
   \end{minipage}\vfill

  \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.7cm,height=4.7cm]{figs/4.pdf} 
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:d}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{figs/6.pdf} 
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:e}
\end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{4.7cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{figs/5.pdf} 
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:f}
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Snapshots of the human following experiment. }
        \label{Snapshots}
\end{figure*}
```

The output is:
[image]

You can see the figures disappear subcaptions
please help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your source code is not complete. Please provide more information about the documentclass and the packages you are using. With `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`
and `\usepackage{subcaption}` using the `example-image-a` your code compiles without any problems and the output looks good.

Comment: note it's almost always bad to specify both width and height in `\includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{`  this will distort the image just specify one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `mdpi` documentclass that causes the issue. I would suggest to use `subfigures` instead of the `minipages`. The following code is based on yours:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\Title{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub3}
\end{subfigure}\\[\baselineskip]

\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub4}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub5}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.7cm, height=4.7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, it worked it fine now.

Comment: also, this is fixed it \\[\baselineskip] instead of the \vfill